# Forcing certain compiler-generated variables into specific ELF sections (with gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, linker, elf

I'll start with the ultimate question: In C with gcc, is it possible to get the value(s) of `__func__` (or equivalently, `__FUNCTION__`) stored in a section other than `.rodata` (or wherever `-mrodata=` points) or subsection thereof?

The full explanation:

Say I have a logging macro:

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) log_internal(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

(The string concatenation operator `##` used in that unary context consumes the preceding comma if and only if the `__VA_ARGS__` list is empty, thereby allowing use of a format string with or without arguments.)

I can then use the macro normally:

```
void my_function(void) {
    LOG("foo!");
    LOG("bar: %p", &bar);
}
```

might print (obviously depending on the implementation of `log_internal`):

```
foo.c:201(my_function) foo!
foo.c:202(my_function) bar: 0x12345678
```

In this case, the format strings (`"foo"` and `"bar: %p"`) and the preprocessor strings (`"foo.c"` and `"my_function"`) are anonymous read only data, and they get placed into the `.rodata` section automatically.

But say I want them to go to a different place (I'm on an embedded platform running almost everything from RAM for speed, but memory constraints are pushing for moving some things into ROM).  It's "easy" to move `__FILE__` and the format string:

```
#define ROM_STR(str) (__extension__({static const __attribute__((__section__(".rom_data"))) char __c[] = (str); (const char *)&__c;}))
#define LOG(fmt, ...) log_internal(ROM_STR(__FILE__), __LINE__, __func__, ROM_STR(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

You can't put an `__attribute__` on an anonymous string, so the `ROM_STR` macro gives it a transient name, affixes it to a specific section, then evaluates to the starting address, so it can substitute cleanly.  This doesn't work if you try to pass a `char *` variable to `LOG` as your format string, but I'm willing to exclude that use case.

Normally, anonymous strings that happen to be identical get combined by the compiler into a single storage location, so every instance of `__FILE__` in one file would share the same runtime address.  With the explicit naming in `ROM_STR`, each instance will get its own storage location, so it probably doesn't actually make sense to use it on `__FILE__`.

However, I would like to use it on `__func__`.  The problem is that `__func__` is not the same kind of magic as `__FILE__`.  From the gcc manual, "Function Names as Strings":

> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function. This name is the unadorned name of the function.
>   ...
>   These identifiers are not preprocessor macros.  In GCC 3.3 and earlier, and in C only, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` were treated as string literals; they could be used to initialize char arrays, and they could be concatenated with other string literas.  GCC 3.4 and later treat them as variables, like `__func__`.

Thus, if you wrap `__func__` with `ROM_STR`, you get

```
error: invalid initializer
```

and if you try to put a section attribute before or after the use of `__func__`, you get

```
error: expected expression before ‘__attribute__’
```

or

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__attribute__’
```

And thus we loop back to the opening question: Is it possible to get `__func__` stored in a section of my choosing?  Maybe I can use `-fdata-sections` and do some linker script magic to get `.rodata.__func__.*` excluded from the rest of `.rodata`?  If so, what is the syntax for globbing with exclusion in a linker script?  In other words, somewhere you have a `*(.rodata*)` - I could put a `*(.rodata.__func__*)` somewhere else, but I would need to modify the original glob to exclude it so I don't get two copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I answered my own question at the end with the `-fdata-sections` business, I just didn't understand the GNU Linker enough to see it.  I don't actually need the globbing with exclusion as long as I specify the `*(.rodata.__func__*)` bit first.  Any sections that glob matches will get marked as used, so a later glob for `*(.rodata*)` won't double count them and copy them somewhere else.  I don't need to tag them with `ROM_STR` at all. Cool!

It's important to note that `-fdata-sections` does actually put each function string into its own `.rodata.__func__.1234` section (I'm not sure what pattern the numbers follow).  I don't know if anonymous strings also get their own sections; if so, I could use the same linker tricks to capture all of the anonymous strings instead of the `ROM_STR` section attribute macro, but it would probably be a bad idea.  `ROM_STR` gets used in the `LOG` macro, so it's guaranteed only to be applied to logging format strings.  If I forced all anonymous strings into ROM with a linker trick, that would include normal message data, and I would pay a runtime performance penalty to access it from flash.  So I don't know if it's even possible, but its advisability would depend on your specific system requirements.

Comment: Here's a handy [reference to linker script syntax](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-1750-ug/p5node10.html)

Comment: As of 2015, gcc no longer does this. See: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=192

Answer (score 3):

One approach, which may be hackier than you'd like, would be to interpose a script to change the section names between compilation and assembly. Eg:

```
gcc -fdata-sections -S -o test.s test.c
sed 's/^\t.section\t\.rodata\.__func__\.[0-9]*/\t.section .rom_data/' -i test.s
gcc -c test.s
```

You could also try writing a clang transformation pass to place the `__func__` declarations in a section of your choosing, or writing an object file manipulation program using [libbfd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library).

Comment: I think the two step process to rename the sections in the intermediate assembly files could definitely work.  With extra (nontrivial) smarts, a script could maybe even pick out the appropriate data if you built without `-fdata-sections`.  But my experiments and further reading on linker scripts show that it's much easier than I thought to place those sections explicitly, so I detailed that in a different answer.

Comment: Also, +1 for the link to BFD.  That could be handy for many things.